# Basic steps for: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( \int_0^x f(a)(x-a)da\right)=\int_0^x f(a)da$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Ho do you find this equality 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( \int_0^x f(a)(x-a)da\right)=\int_0^x f(a)da\,?
$$

Step by step...

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which is it, $a-x$ or $x-a$?? The original question included $(a-x)$, then you changed the image to show $(x-a)$, and now you rolled it back to $(a-x)$. So which is it?

Comment: @teadawg1337 Sorry, it was: x-a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Leibniz's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) for differentiating under the integral we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x (x-a)f(a)\,da&=\color{blue}{\left.\left((x-a)f(a)\right)\right|_{a=x}\,\frac{d}{dx}(x)}+\color{red}{\int_0^x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}((x-a)f(a))\,da}\\\\&=\color{blue}{0}+\color{red}{\int_0^x f(a)\,da}\\\\&=\int_0^x f(a)\,da \end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer !

Comment: You're quite welcome!  My pleasure.  -Mark

Answer (score 3):

One may write
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( \int_0^x f(a)(x-a)da\right)&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( x \int_0^x f(a)da-\int_0^x af(a)da\right)
\\\\&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x \int_0^x f(a)da\right)-\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x a f(a)da
\\\\&=\left(1 \cdot  \int_0^x f(a)da+x \cdot f(x) \right)-x\cdot f(x)
\\\\&=\int_0^x f(a)da
\end{align}
$$ as announced.

Comment: Switch the $a-x$ to $x-a$ in the first line, and you get the OP's problem.

Comment: @SimpleArt The OP edited the question after this answer was posted

Comment: @teadawg1337 Ah, isn't that a nuisance.

Comment: @SimpleArt Thank you.

Comment: Thank you soo much !! This is a perfect answer !! :)

Comment: @DoHe You are welcome.